# linking an image from a db asp.net mvc 4

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, hyperlink

I'm trying to link an image to a page thats coming from a db.

```
    @foreach (var item in model)
   <tr>
   <td>
   <img width="50" height="50" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product", new { item.ProductId})"/>
   </td>
   ...
```

how can I now have this image, when clicked, go to a certain action

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your image in an `a` tag.

```
<a href="SOME_URL_HERE">
    <img width="50" height="50" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product", new { item.ProductId})"/>
</a>
```

Comment: have tried it before but get a 404 when I declare a URL for the href